# Mongodb failing to start using init script with dbpath on mounted drive

Tags: linux, mongodb

I've been trying to set up a mongodb instance (2.6.11) on my CentOS 6.3 to use a data location on a different drive because of space constraints on the default location of /var/lib/mongo

I've changed the dbpath parameter in /etc/mongo.conf and created the appropriate location on the alternate drive, e.g. /mnt/newdrive/mongo.
To make sure the service can access the new location, I've set the user and group to mongod with

```
chown -R mongod:mongod /mnt/newdrive/mongo
```

If I start the daemon using the commands

```
sudo service mongod start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/mongod start
```

the starting fails with

```
std::exception: boost:filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/mnt/newdrive/mongo", terminating
```

If I start with

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongo.conf
```

The process starts happily, though, to shut it down I need to issue

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongo.conf --shutdown
```

as the service/init.d scripts don't work.

The same issue is apparent when creating a symlink /mnt/newdrive/mongo -> /var/lib/mongo instead of changing the configuration (the 'permission denied' error, in that case, is on the symlink).
The new drive is already accessible by different accounts for other purposes and it's mounted, fstab reporting

```
/dev/sb1/ /mnt/newdrive ext4 defaults 1 2
```

the ACL is as follows:

```
# file: mnt/newdrive/mongo
# owner: mongod
# group: mongod
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Many thanks,
Alberto

Comment: Allowing traversing of the intermediate folder with chmod -R o+x /mnt/newdrive seems to have done the trick. I suspect that's a bit of a compromise though. Or is it?